# Gulp src - маска на выбираемые элементы

Tags: gulp, jekyll

Всем доброго времени суток. Использую сайт на **jekyll**. Есть одна загвоздка. При создании поста в папке `_posts` также создаю подпапку `_temp`, где хранятся не обработанные изображения. После того, как пост готов, нужно вручную копировать необходимые изображения из подпапки `_temp` в `images/cat/:year/:name`. Логично, что этот процесс лишний и его надо засунуть в таскер. Я использую **Gulp**.
Хочется с помощью **Gulp** выбирать изображения подходящие под маску, например, `("0-9"||"0-9thumb")+".jpg||.png||.mp4||.webp"`, т.е. имя медиа может быть 1thumb.jpg или 3.mp4, и перемещать их в нужную папку.

Прошу помочь разобраться как лучше сделать, возможно уже есть готовые решения. В документации Gulp.src не нашел фильтров по маске.

Возможно есть готовый инструмент в **jekyll** ?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решения в интернете не нашел, посему пришлось думать как это обойти. И идея пришла следующая - объединить **Gulp** таскер с питоном (**python**).
Весь скрипт написал на Python, используя библиотеку `import os`. Туда же засунул обработку изображений, добавление вотермарка и в `gulpfile.js` добавил новый таск - запуска скрипта из питона. Для этого из npm пакета скачал и установил run (`npm i gulp-run`) и вызвал скрипт:

```
gulp.task('copy-images', function(){
    return run('python _main.py').exec();
});
```

Файл _main.py разместил на один уровень с `gulpfile.js`

Описывать как реализовывал в питоне скрипт фильтрации думаю смысла нет. Библиотекой `os` реализовал навигацию, с помощью `re.match` и регулярок взял необходимые файли и с помощью `shutil` скопировал в нужное место. Если `distanation` не существовал, то кэчил его и создавал с помощью `os.makedirs(..)`

done

Comment: отличный костыль

Comment: @MoloF, люблю, умею, практикую